How to Extract Information from a Large Markdown File to Fill a JSON Using OpenAI?
I have a large markdown (MD) file from which I need to extract information to fill a JSON file. How can I provide the MD file as context in an OpenAI request to generate the filled JSON? I tried dividing it into chunks, but the results aren't very good. One issue I face is that the MD file contains multiple scenarios, and I need to determine which one is used. If I provide the file in chunks, the GPT model fills the scenario case in the JSON with the first mentioned scenario, but it needs to read the entire document first to understand which scenario is actually used.
I tried to split the md file in chunks to respect the context window

You could include it as part of your user message. For example: 'In this markdown file. . . then say what you want it to do. Then copy the text from the markdown file. Pretend it's almost human :)

A general approach could be:

Summarize scenarios one by one to make them shorter or extract key data for decision
Feed summarized data to the LLM again to understand which scenario is used

Depending on the data, you may be good with the first step only, if you can make a decision algorithmically after that.
Besides that, you could use another LLM with a larger context window.
